# how to stop letter repeating itself python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.8

I am making a code which takes in jumble word and returns a unjumbled word , the data.json contains a list and here take a word one-by-one and check if it contains all the characters of the word and later checking if the length is same , but the problem is when i enter a word as helol then the l is checked twice and giving me some other outputs including the main one(hello). i know why does it happen but i cant get a fix to it

```py
import json

val = open("data.json")
val1 = json.load(val)#loads the list


a = input("Enter a Jumbled word ")#takes a word from user
a = list(a)#changes into list to iterate


for x in val1:#iterates words from list
    for somethin in a:#iterates letters from list
        if somethin in list(x):#checks if the letter is in the iterated word
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:#checks if the loop ended correctly (that means word has same letters)
        if len(a) != len(list(x)):#checks if it has same number of letters
            continue#returns
        else:
            print(x)#continues the loop to see if there are more like that
```

EDIT: many people wanted the json file so here it is

```json
['Torres Strait Creole', 'good bye', 'agon', "queen's guard", 'animosity', 'price list', 'subjective', 'means', 'severe', 'knockout', 'life-threatening', 'entry into the war', 'dominion', 'damnify', 'packsaddle', 'hallucinate', 'lumpy', 'inception', 'Blankenese', 'cacophonous', 'zeptomole', 'floccinaucinihilipilificate', 'abashed', 'abacterial', 'ableism', 'invade', 'cohabitant', 'handicapped', 'obelus', 'triathlon', 'habitue', 'instigate', 'Gladstone Gander', 'Linked Data', 'seeded player', 'mozzarella', 'gymnast', 'gravitational force', 'Friedelehe', 'open up', 'bundt cake', 'riffraff', 'resourceful', 'wheedle', 'city center', 'gorgonzola', 'oaf', 'auf', 'oafs', 'galoot', 'imbecile', 'lout', 'moron', 'news leak', 'crate', 'aggregator', 'cheating', 'negative growth', 'zero growth', 'defer', 'ride back', 'drive back', 'start back', 'shy back', 'spring back', 'shrink back', 'shy away', 'abderian', 'unable', 'font manager', 'font management software', 'consortium', 'gown', 'inject', 'ISO 639', 'look up', 'cross-eyed', 'squinting', 'health club', 'fitness facility', 'steer', 'sunbathe', 'combatives', 'HTH', 'hope that helps', 'How The Hell', 'distributed', 'plum cake', 'liberalization', 'macchiato', 'caffè macchiato', 'beach volley', 'exult', 'jubilate', 'beach volleyball', 'be beached', 'affogato', 'gigabyte', 'terabyte', 'petabyte', 'undressed', 'decameter', 'sensual', 'boundary marker', 'poor man', 'cohabitee', 'night sleep', 'protruding ears', 'three quarters of an hour', 'spermophilus', 'spermophilus stricto sensu', "devil's advocate", 'sacred king', 'sacral king', 'myr', 'million years', 'obtuse-angled', 'inconsolable', 'neurotic', 'humiliating', 'mortifying', 'theological', 'rematch', 'varıety', 'be short', 'ontological', 'taxonomic', 'taxonomical', 'toxicology testing', 'on the job training', 'boulder', 'unattackable', 'inviolable', 'resinous', 'resiny', 'ionizing radiation', 'citrus grove', 'comic book shop', 'preparatory measure', 'written account', 'brittle', 'locker', 'baozi', 'bao', 'bau', 'humbow', 'nunu', 'bausak', 'pow', 'pau', 'yesteryear', 'fire drill', 'rotted', 'putto', 'overthrow', 'ankle monitor', 'somewhat stupid', 'a little stupid', 'semordnilap', 'pangram', 'emordnilap', 'person with a sunlamp tan', 'tittle', 'incompatible', 'autumn wind', 'dairyman', 'chesty', 'lacustrine', 'chronophotograph', 'chronophoto', 'leg lace', 'ankle lace', 'ankle lock', 'Babelfy', 'ventricular', 'recurrent', 'long-lasting', 'long-standing', 'long standing', 'sea bass', 'reap', 'break wind', 'chase away', 'spark', 'speckle', 'take back', 'Westphalian', 'Aeolic Greek', 'startup', 'abseiling', 'impure', 'bottle cork', 'paralympic', 'work out', 'might', 'ice-cream man', 'ice cream man', 'ice cream maker', 'ice-cream maker', 'traveling', 'special delivery', 'prizefighter', 'abs', 'ab', 'churro', 'pilfer', 'dehumanize', 'fertilize', 'inseminate', 'digitalize', 'fluke', 'stroke of luck', 'decontaminate', 'abandonware', 'manzanita', 'tule', 'jackrabbit', 'system administrator', 'system admin', 'springtime lethargy', 'Palatinean', 'organized religion', 'bearing puller', 'wheel puller', 'gear puller', 'shot', 'normalize', 'palindromic', 'lancet window', 'terminological', 'back of head', 'dragon food', 'barbel', 'Central American Spanish', 'basis', 'birthmark', 'blood vessel', 'ribes', 'dog-rose', 'dreadful', 'freckle', 'free of charge', 'weather verb', 'weather sentence', 'gipsy', 'gypsy', 'glutton', 'hump', 'low voice', 'meek', 'moist', 'river mouth', 'turbid', 'multitude', 'palate', 'peak of mountain', 'poetry', 'pure', 'scanty', 'spicy', 'spicey', 'spruce', 'surface', 'infected', 'copulate', 'dilute', 'dislocate', 'grow up', 'hew', 'hinder', 'infringe', 'inhabit', 'marry off', 'offend', 'pass by', 'brother of a man', 'brother of a woman', 'sister of a man', 'sister of a woman', 'agricultural farm', 'result in', 'rebel', 'strew', 'scatter', 'sway', 'tread', 'tremble', 'hog', 'circuit breaker', 'Southern Quechua', 'safety pin', 'baby pin', 'college student', 'university student', 'pinus sibirica', 'Siberian pine', 'have lunch', 'floppy', 'slack', 'sloppy', 'wishi-washi', 'turn around', 'bogeyman', 'selfish', 'Talossan', 'biomembrane', 'biological membrane', 'self-sufficiency', 'underevaluation', 'underestimation', 'opisthenar', 'prosody', 'Kumhar Bhag Paharia', 'psychoneurotic', 'psychoneurosis', 'levant', "couldn't-care-less attitude", 'noctambule', 'acid-free paper', 'decontaminant', 'woven', 'wheaten', 'waste-ridden', 'war-ridden', 'violence-ridden', 'unwritten', 'typewritten', 'spoken', 'abiogenetically', 'rasp', 'abstractly', 'cyclically', 'acyclically', 'acyclic', 'ad hoc', 'spare tire', 'spare wheel', 'spare tyre', 'prefabricated', 'ISO 9000', 'Barquisimeto', 'Maracay', 'Ciudad Guayana', 'San Cristobal', 'Barranquilla', 'Arequipa', 'Trujillo', 'Cusco', 'Callao', 'Cochabamba', 'Goiânia', 'Campinas', 'Fortaleza', 'Florianópolis', 'Rosario', 'Mendoza', 'Bariloche', 'temporality', 'papyrus sedge', 'paper reed', 'Indian matting plant', 'Nile grass', 'softly softly', 'abductive reasoning', 'abductive inference', 'retroduction', 'Salzburgian', 'cymotrichous', 'access point', 'wireless access point', 'dynamic DNS', 'IP address', 'electrolyte', 'helical', 'hydrometer', 'intranet', 'jumper', 'MAC address', 'Media Access Control address', 'nickel–cadmium battery', 'Ni-Cd battery', 'oscillograph', 'overload', 'photovoltaic', 'photovoltaic cell', 'refractor telescope', 'autosome', 'bacterial artificial chromosome', 'plasmid', 'nucleobase', 'base pair', 'base sequence', 'chromosomal deletion', 'deletion', 'deletion mutation', 'gene deletion', 'chromosomal inversion', 'comparative genomics', 'genomics', 'cytogenetics', 'DNA replication', 'DNA repair', 'DNA sequence', 'electrophoresis', 'functional genomics', 'retroviral', 'retroviral infection', 'acceptance criteria', 'batch processing', 'business rule', 'code review', 'configuration management', 'entity–relationship model', 'lifecycle', 'object code', 'prototyping', 'pseudocode', 'referential', 'reusability', 'self-join', 'timestamp', 'accredited', 'accredited translator', 'certify', 'certified translation', 'computer-aided design', 'computer-aided', 'computer-assisted', 'management system', 'computer-aided translation', 'computer-assisted translation', 'machine-aided translation', 'conference interpreter', 'freelance translator', 'literal translation', 'mother-tongue', 'whispered interpreting', 'simultaneous interpreting', 'simultaneous interpretation', 'base anhydride', 'binary compound', 'absorber', 'absorption coefficient', 'attenuation coefficient', 'active solar heater', 'ampacity', 'amorphous semiconductor', 'amorphous silicon', 'flowerpot', 'antireflection coating', 'antireflection', 'armored cable', 'electric arc', 'breakdown voltage','casing', 'facing', 'lining', 'assumption of Mary', 'auscultation']
```

Just a example and the dictionary is full of items

Comment: You don't need to turn `a` into a list. You can iterate over the string directly, which is why `list(a)` works in the first place.

Comment: `for x in keys` - what is `keys`? Are you basically looking for anagrams?

Comment: keys means the val1

Comment: I think your code has a potential bug. You check that each letter in your input exists in a key. And then you check whether the word has the same length is as the key itself. Both requirements are satisfied for `'hello'` vs `'heloo'`, but they're obviously not anagrams.

Comment: @chepner i didnt know that but still anyways it wasnt being used later too but i cant find a way to solve it could you please help me

Comment: @Reti43 The problem when i type hello i get a output like hotel because it has same letters but i cant find a way to prevent it i cant get a example how to solve

Comment: What does your JSON file look like?

Comment: im not trying to find anagrams im saying like if i give word like ehlot then it should return me hotel (it does) and in other case if i give hlloe it should give me hello , but it gets stuck

Comment: @DarkKnight Json works perfectly but the other code doesnt properly

Comment: There is absolutely no logic in your code that can change "othel" into "hotel" except (possibly) by chance

Comment: Ive shared my json file

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: @DarkKnight this is what is stored in that file and i read it and use that , the mistake is in code and not the jsonnn

Comment: If your file contains the data as shown, you will get an exception when you try to execute json.load()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you are trying to identify all possible matches for the jumbled string in your list. You could sort the letters in the jumbled word and match the resulting list against sorted lists of the words in your data file.

```
sorted_jumbled_word = sorted(a)
for word in val1:
    if len(sorted_jumbled_word) == len(word) and sorted(word) == sorted_jumbled_word:
        print(word)
```

Checking by length first reduces unnecessary sorting. If doing this repeatedly, you might want to create a dictionary of the words in the data file with their sorted versions, to avoid having to repeatedly sort them.

There are spaces and punctuation in some of the terms in your word list. If you want to make the comparison ignoring spaces then remove them from both the jumbled word and the list of unjumbled words, using e.g. `word = word.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: sounds nice I need to try this

Comment: This could lead to ambiguous results. For example, if the input is "beors" the *correct* word could be "sober", "robes" or "bores". Which one would be correct?

Comment: @DarkKnight i even dont care if it gives many results , actually i want them